# How to get different cache_times from different inline queries?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

just started to use the python-telegram-bot library and I made my own bot using their examples and documentations, but still can't get my bot to do something that should be rather simple, which is to have different cache_times for different inline queries. This is the involved code:

```
    def inline_opt(update, context):
        results = [
        InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id=uuid4(),
            title = "QUERY1",
            input_message_content = InputTextMessageContent(
                "blah blah")),

        InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id=uuid4(),
            title = "QUERY2",
            input_message_content = InputTextMessageContent(
                "Blah blah "))
        ]

    update.inline_query.answer(results, cache_time=0)
```

It works fine, except that I want the first query to have a cache_time of 0 seconds and the other one to have a cache_time of x seconds. Sorry if it's a dumb question but couldn't get an answer on the doc or in the telegram group.

Comment: Have you tried sending separate results depending on your query? something like `if query == "QUERY1": result1= [InlineQueryResultArticle(...)] ; update.inline_query.answer(result1,cache_time1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cache_time` is a parameter of `inline_query.answer()` which means you need to filter the queries you receive to create a tailored answer with its particular `cache_time`.

```
import time

def inlinequery(update, context):
    query = update.inline_query.query
    if query=="time":
        results = [
            InlineQueryResultArticle(
                id=uuid4(),
                title="time",
                input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(
                    "time({!s}): {!s}".format(query,time.asctime(time.localtime()))))
            ]
        seconds = 1;
        update.inline_query.answer(results,cache_time=seconds)
    elif query=="hora":
        results = [
            InlineQueryResultArticle(
                id=uuid4(),
                title="hora",
                input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(
                    "Time({!s}): {!s}".format(query,time.asctime(time.localtime()))))
            ]
        seconds = 60;
        update.inline_query.answer(results,cache_time=seconds)
```